# Material-ui adding Link to Radio Button component from react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router, material-ui

Hellou! I have 2 radiobuttons and I want to add a link.
I tried to do it the way:

```
    <RadioButton
      value="/searchByArtistAndName"
      label="Artist and Name"
      style={styles.radioButton}
      containerElement={<Link to="/searchByArtistAndName"/>}
    />
```

But containerElement is not defined for RadioButton. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can put any react component in the label property, not just a text string.

```
<RadioButton
  label={<Link to="/your_route" />}
  ...
/>
```